How to unpack a string into multiple columns in a Polars DataFrame using expressions?
I have a Polars DataFrame containing a column with strings representing 'sparse' sector exposures, like this:
df = pl.DataFrame(
    pl.Series("sector_exposure", [
        "Technology=0.207;Financials=0.090;Health Care=0.084;Consumer Discretionary=0.069", 
        "Financials=0.250;Health Care=0.200;Consumer Staples=0.150;Industrials=0.400"
    ])
)




sector_exposure




Technology=0.207;Financials=0.090;Health Care=0.084;Consumer Discretionary=0.069


Financials=0.250;Health Care=0.200;Consumer Staples=0.150;Industrials=0.400



I want to "unpack" this string into new columns for each sector (e.g., Technology, Financials, Health Care) with associated values or a polars struct with sector names as fields and exposure values.
I'm looking for a more efficient solution using polars expressions only, without resorting to Python loops (or python mapped functions). Can anyone provide guidance on how to accomplish this?
This is what I have come up with so far - which works in producing the desired struct but is a little slow.
(
    df["sector_exposure"]
    .str
    .split(";")
    .map_elements(lambda x: {entry.split('=')[0]: float(entry.split('=')[1]) for entry in x},
                  skip_nulls=True,
                  )
)

Output:
shape: (2,)
Series: 'sector_exposure' [struct[6]]
[
    {0.207,0.09,0.084,0.069,null,null}
    {null,0.25,0.2,null,0.15,0.4}
]

Thanks!

There are potentially two ways to do it that I can think of.
Regex extract
df.with_columns(pl.col('sector_exposure').str.extract(x+r"=(\d+\.\d+)").cast(pl.Float64).alias(x) 
                for x in ["Technology", "Financials", "Health Care", "Consumer Discretionary",
                          "Consumer Staples","Industrials"])

shape: (2, 7)
┌────────────────┬────────────┬────────────┬─────────────┬────────────────┬──────────┬─────────────┐
│ sector_exposur ┆ Technology ┆ Financials ┆ Health Care ┆ Consumer       ┆ Consumer ┆ Industrials │
│ e              ┆ ---        ┆ ---        ┆ ---         ┆ Discretionary  ┆ Staples  ┆ ---         │
│ ---            ┆ f64        ┆ f64        ┆ f64         ┆ ---            ┆ ---      ┆ f64         │
│ str            ┆            ┆            ┆             ┆ f64            ┆ f64      ┆             │
╞════════════════╪════════════╪════════════╪═════════════╪════════════════╪══════════╪═════════════╡
│ Technology=0.2 ┆ 0.207      ┆ 0.09       ┆ 0.084       ┆ 0.069          ┆ null     ┆ null        │
│ 07;Financials= ┆            ┆            ┆             ┆                ┆          ┆             │
│ 0.090;Health   ┆            ┆            ┆             ┆                ┆          ┆             │
│ Care=0.084;Con ┆            ┆            ┆             ┆                ┆          ┆             │
│ sumer Discreti ┆            ┆            ┆             ┆                ┆          ┆             │
│ onary=0.069    ┆            ┆            ┆             ┆                ┆          ┆             │
│ Financials=0.2 ┆ null       ┆ 0.25       ┆ 0.2         ┆ null           ┆ 0.15     ┆ 0.4         │
│ 50;Health Care ┆            ┆            ┆             ┆                ┆          ┆             │
│ =0.200;Consume ┆            ┆            ┆             ┆                ┆          ┆             │
│ r Staples=0.15 ┆            ┆            ┆             ┆                ┆          ┆             │
│ 0;Industrials= ┆            ┆            ┆             ┆                ┆          ┆             │
│ 0.400          ┆            ┆            ┆             ┆                ┆          ┆             │
└────────────────┴────────────┴────────────┴─────────────┴────────────────┴──────────┴─────────────┘

In this one we're counting on all the numbers being decimal (you could tweak the regex to get around this a bit) and all the sectors being prespecified in the generator within with_columns
Split and pivot
(
    df
    .with_columns(str_split=pl.col('sector_exposure').str.split(';'))
    .explode('str_split')
    .with_columns(
        pl.col('str_split')
        .str.split('=')
        .list.to_struct(fields=['sector','value'])
        )
    .unnest('str_split')
    .pivot(values='value',index='sector_exposure',columns='sector',aggregate_function='first')
    .with_columns(pl.exclude('sector_exposure').cast(pl.Float64))
    )
shape: (2, 7)
┌────────────────┬────────────┬────────────┬─────────────┬────────────────┬──────────┬─────────────┐
│ sector_exposur ┆ Technology ┆ Financials ┆ Health Care ┆ Consumer       ┆ Consumer ┆ Industrials │
│ e              ┆ ---        ┆ ---        ┆ ---         ┆ Discretionary  ┆ Staples  ┆ ---         │
│ ---            ┆ f64        ┆ f64        ┆ f64         ┆ ---            ┆ ---      ┆ f64         │
│ str            ┆            ┆            ┆             ┆ f64            ┆ f64      ┆             │
╞════════════════╪════════════╪════════════╪═════════════╪════════════════╪══════════╪═════════════╡
│ Technology=0.2 ┆ 0.207      ┆ 0.09       ┆ 0.084       ┆ 0.069          ┆ null     ┆ null        │
│ 07;Financials= ┆            ┆            ┆             ┆                ┆          ┆             │
│ 0.090;Health   ┆            ┆            ┆             ┆                ┆          ┆             │
│ Care=0.084;Con ┆            ┆            ┆             ┆                ┆          ┆             │
│ sumer Discreti ┆            ┆            ┆             ┆                ┆          ┆             │
│ onary=0.069    ┆            ┆            ┆             ┆                ┆          ┆             │
│ Financials=0.2 ┆ null       ┆ 0.25       ┆ 0.2         ┆ null           ┆ 0.15     ┆ 0.4         │
│ 50;Health Care ┆            ┆            ┆             ┆                ┆          ┆             │
│ =0.200;Consume ┆            ┆            ┆             ┆                ┆          ┆             │
│ r Staples=0.15 ┆            ┆            ┆             ┆                ┆          ┆             │
│ 0;Industrials= ┆            ┆            ┆             ┆                ┆          ┆             │
│ 0.400          ┆            ┆            ┆             ┆                ┆          ┆             │
└────────────────┴────────────┴────────────┴─────────────┴────────────────┴──────────┴─────────────┘

In this one you do a "round" of splitting at the semi colon and then explode. Then you split again on the equal but you turn that into a struct which you then unnest. From there you pivot the sectors up to columns.
If the sectors existed in the same order then you could use str.extract_groups but with varying orders I don't think it works.

Nice solution! I was working on an approach using the str namespace to make the string a valid JSON. Then, str.json_decode() could be used directly. Your solution(s) seem cleaner though.

Awesome! I just tried both on a dataset of 1.7m rows:

your first solution (regex) took 410ms
your second solution (split & pivot) took 3.73s
my baseline solution takes 10.2s

The groups are not guaranteed to occur in the same order, however in some cases (like this specific example) I know all the fields up front and so can apply solution 1.
Thank you very much for your help

As was mentioned in another comment, you can perform a couple of replacements to treat these values as json. This will assist if you don't have a listing of all possible fields in advance:
import polars as pl
from polars import col

df = pl.DataFrame(
    [
        pl.Series("sector_exposure", [
            'Technology=0.207;Financials=0.090;Health Care=0.084;Consumer Discretionary=0.069',
            'Financials=0.250;Health Care=0.200;Consumer Staples=0.150;Industrials=0.400'
            ], dtype=pl.String),
    ]
)

print(
    df.select(
        pl.format(
            '{{}}',
            col('sector_exposure').str.replace_many([';', '=',], [',', ':'])
            .str.replace_all(r'([a-zA-Z ]+)', r'"$1"')
        )
        .str.json_decode()
        .name.keep()
    )
    .unnest('sector_exposure')
)
# shape: (2, 6)
# ┌────────────┬────────────┬─────────────┬────────────────────────┬──────────────────┬─────────────┐
# │ Technology ┆ Financials ┆ Health Care ┆ Consumer Discretionary ┆ Consumer Staples ┆ Industrials │
# │ ---        ┆ ---        ┆ ---         ┆ ---                    ┆ ---              ┆ ---         │
# │ f64        ┆ f64        ┆ f64         ┆ f64                    ┆ f64              ┆ f64         │
# ╞════════════╪════════════╪═════════════╪════════════════════════╪══════════════════╪═════════════╡
# │ 0.207      ┆ 0.09       ┆ 0.084       ┆ 0.069                  ┆ null             ┆ null        │
# │ null       ┆ 0.25       ┆ 0.2         ┆ null                   ┆ 0.15             ┆ 0.4         │
# └────────────┴────────────┴─────────────┴────────────────────────┴──────────────────┴─────────────┘

another similar approach avoiding the regex replacement backreference (thanks @jquirious)
print(
    df.select(
        pl.format(
            '{"{}}',
            col('sector_exposure').str.replace_many([';', '=',], [',"', '":'])
        )
        .str.json_decode()
        .name.keep()
    )
    .unnest('sector_exposure')
)
shape: (2, 6)
┌────────────┬────────────┬─────────────┬────────────────────────┬──────────────────┬─────────────┐
│ Technology ┆ Financials ┆ Health Care ┆ Consumer Discretionary ┆ Consumer Staples ┆ Industrials │
│ ---        ┆ ---        ┆ ---         ┆ ---                    ┆ ---              ┆ ---         │
│ f64        ┆ f64        ┆ f64         ┆ f64                    ┆ f64              ┆ f64         │
╞════════════╪════════════╪═════════════╪════════════════════════╪══════════════════╪═════════════╡
│ 0.207      ┆ 0.09       ┆ 0.084       ┆ 0.069                  ┆ null             ┆ null        │
│ null       ┆ 0.25       ┆ 0.2         ┆ null                   ┆ 0.15             ┆ 0.4         │
└────────────┴────────────┴─────────────┴────────────────────────┴──────────────────┴─────────────┘


Very neat approach. Just out of interest, it seems avoiding replacement backreferences can help efficiency quite a bit. I tried: pl.format("{\"{}}", pl.col("sector_exposure").str.replace_many(["=", ";"], ["\":", ",\""])) - combined with .collect(streaming=True) it is "super fast".

Another way to accomplish the goal
(
  df
    .select(
      pl.col('sector_exposure')
        .str.split(";")
        .explode()
        .str.split("=")
        .list.to_struct(fields = ['sector', 'value'])
    )
    .unnest('sector_exposure')
    .with_columns(pl.col('value').cast(pl.Float32))
)

